# camel - get xml from url

Tags: java, jetty, apache-camel

I want to build simple camel application, which will get xml from URL and then send it to another URL.

I was trying with:

```
from("jetty:http://.../sitemap.xml?delay=5000")
        .process(new Processor() {
                    .....
                })
        .to("http://...");
```

and i found couple of problems:

1) i cant get content from the URL automaticly - something is invoking only when i open web browser with the sitemap.xml, but i want, that my script will connect by it self fo every 5 seconds and receive content

2) when i'm trying to connect to localhost i have problem with socket - `java.net.SocketException: Permission denied

maybe you have some simple example to do something what i need ?
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[camel-jetty](http://camel.apache.org/jetty.html) is for exposing http endpoints, you need to use [camel-http4](http://camel.apache.org/http4.html) to consume from remote http sites...

also, use [camel-timer](http://camel.apache.org/timer.html) for periodic operations like this...

```
from("timer://foo?fixedRate=true&delay=0&period=5000")
    .to("http4://.../sitemap.xml")
    ...;
```